# passing arg 1 of `puts' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, puts

```
struct{
char nome[30],rua [50],bairro [20],cidade [30],se [3] ;
int na, exc, numero;
long int CEP;
}typedef endereco;

main(){
       endereco agenda[20];
       int i, j, opc, opc1=0, opc2, eopc ;
       char pnome[30], pbairro[20], pcidade[30], enome[30];

while (opc!=4){
       system("cls");
       printf("Agenda facs, digite a opção: \n|\t1-incluir\t|\n|\t2-Consultar\t|\n|\t3-excluir\t|\n|\t4-sair\t |\nDigite a opção ");
       scanf("%d",&opc);
       fflush(stdin);
       switch (opc){
                    case 1:
                         system("cls");
                         printf("Digite os Dados a seguir para incluir no # %d :\n",opc1+1);
                         agenda[opc1].na=opc1+1;
                         agenda[opc1].exc=0;
                         printf("Digite o nome: ");
                         gets(agenda[opc1].nome);
                         printf("Digite a Rua: ");
                         gets(agenda[opc1].rua);                         
                         printf("Digite o Bairro: ");
                         gets(agenda[opc1].bairro);
                         printf("Digite o numero: ");
                         fflush(stdin);
                         scanf("%d",&agenda[opc1].numero);
                         fflush(stdin);                         
                         printf("Digite a Cidade: ");
                         gets(agenda[opc1].cidade); 
                         printf("Digite a Sigla do Estado: ");
                         gets(agenda[opc1].se);
                         printf("Digite o CEP: ");
                         fflush(stdin);
                         scanf("%d",&agenda[opc1].CEP);
                         fflush(stdin); 
                         opc1++;
                         break;
                    case 2:
                         system("cls");
                         printf("\n|\t1-Nome\t|\n|\t2-Bairro\t|\n|\t3-Cidade\t|\n|\tDigite a opção ");
                         scanf("%d",&opc2);
                         printf("\t|\n");                                       
                         fflush(stdin);                         
                                       switch (opc2){
                                              case 1:
                                                   system("cls");
                                                   printf("Qual o nome a procurar? ");
                                                   gets(pnome);
                                                   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                                                                     if(strcmp(pnome,agenda[i].nome)==0){
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero Agenda: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].na);                                                                     printf("\n\tNome: ");
                                                                     printf("\n\tNome: ");                                                                     
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].nome);
                                                                     printf("\n\tRua: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].rua);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tBairro: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].bairro);
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].numero);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tCidade: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].cidade); 
                                                                     printf("\n\tEstado: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].se);
                                                                     printf("\n\tCEP: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].CEP);
                                                                     printf("\n\t______________");}}
                                                   break;                  
                                              case 2:
                                                   system("cls");
                                                   printf("Qual o Bairro a procurar? ");
                                                   gets(pbairro);                                                   
                                                   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                                                                     if(strcmp(pbairro,agenda[i].bairro)==0){
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero Agenda: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].na);                                                                     printf("\n\tNome: ");
                                                                     printf("\n\tNome: ");                                                                     
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].nome);
                                                                     printf("\n\tRua: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].rua);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tBairro: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].bairro);
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].numero);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tCidade: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].cidade); 
                                                                     printf("\n\tEstado: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].se);
                                                                     printf("\n\tCEP: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].CEP);
                                                                     printf("\n\t______________");}}
                                                   break;
                                              case 3:
                                                   system("cls");
                                                   printf("Qual a Cidade a procurar? ");
                                                   gets(pcidade);                                                   
                                                   for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                                                                     if(strcmp(pbairro,agenda[i].cidade)==0){
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero Agenda: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].na);                                                                  
                                                                     printf("\n\tNome: ");                                                                     
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].nome);
                                                                     printf("\n\tRua: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].rua);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tBairro: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].bairro);
                                                                     printf("\n\tNumero: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].numero);                         
                                                                     printf("\n\tCidade: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].cidade); 
                                                                     printf("\n\tEstado: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].se);
                                                                     printf("\n\tCEP: ");
                                                                     puts(agenda[i].CEP);
                                                                     printf("\n\t______________");}}
                                                   break;}
                    case 3:
                         system("cls");
                         printf("Digite o Numero da Agenda que deseja excluir");
                         gets(enome);
                         for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                                           if(strcmp(enome,agenda[i].nome)==0){
                                           printf("\n\tNumero Agenda: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].na);                                                                     
                                           printf("\n\tNome: ");                                                                     
                                           puts(agenda[i].nome);
                                           printf("\n\tRua: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].rua);                         
                                           printf("\n\tBairro: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].bairro);
                                           printf("\n\tNumero: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].numero);                         
                                           printf("\n\tCidade: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].cidade); 
                                           printf("\n\tEstado: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].se);
                                           printf("\n\tCEP: ");
                                           puts(agenda[i].CEP);
                                           printf("\n\t______________");}}
                         printf("\n\tDigite o Numero Agenda do Nome na qual voce quer excluir: ");
                         fflush(stdin); 
                         scanf("%d",&i);
                         fflush(stdin);
                         if(agenda[i].exc==0){
                                              printf("\n\t%d . %s \n\tDeseja excluir esse contato?\n\t1-Sim\n\t2-Nao\n\tOpcao: ",agenda[i].na,agenda[i].nome);
                                              fflush(stdin);
                                              scanf("%d",&eopc);
                                              fflush(stdin);
                                              switch (eopc){
                                                     case 1:
                                                          agenda[i].exc=1;
                                                          printf("\t\nNumero excluido !");
                                                          break;
                                                     case 2:
                                                          printf("\t\nNumero nao excluido !");
                                                          break;}}}}



  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Hello :D
This program was build, or trying to, be a notebook that you can save contacts.
But i'm getting this warning, and when the 'puts' come in the program, it crashes.
Someone can help ?

> [Warning] passing arg 1 of `puts' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast

Thanks.

Comment: Why does everyone try to `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is defined on Windows to flush any data from the input buffer.  It is undefined behaviour according to Standard C, POSIX and most Unix-like systems, but it does have a defined (useful) meaning in a Windows environment.

Comment: well, i think fflush(stdin) causes to the memory when you digit something on %d it still saves your 'enter' and when you do a gets, or a %c it jumps cuz in the imput memory already has a 'enter', skipping the process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't know it's defined on Windows, wow! So much for conspiracy theories :(

Comment: TL;DR. [SSCCEE](http://SSCCE.org) is your friend. _Short_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> puts(agenda[i].na);
> ```

In your code `agenda[i].na` is an `int`. You can't print it with `puts`, try `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n", agenda[i].na);
```

> and when the 'puts' come in the program, it crashes.

You are tricking `puts` into using a random integer as a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, it works here. i didn't know that puts cant print numbers, my mistake.

Comment: Have another problem here, the first switch is passing directly to case 3, what should i do?

Comment: @MatheusPereira Your code is overly complex and poorly indented. However, I believe there's a `break;` missing right before `case 3`. Try to restructure your code, and maybe break it into functions.

Comment: `puts()` is short for `put string`, meaning 'output the data from a string'.  It's mnemonic.

Comment: @cnicutar thanks, was missing a second break for switch 1 in the inner switch, was missing that. i'm sorry about this code, i'm new on that, and trying to improve myself, just discovered this website now, prob gonna learn more here. thanks for the awnser.

Comment: And I dont know yet how to use functions, need to study a lil more how it works.